# How to compare strings containing numbers just by letters in C

Tags: c, string, string-comparison, scanf

I need to compare strings comparing letters and numbers just by letters and appearance of a number in C.

For example strings `"first%dsecond%dj"` should be considered equal to any string like `"first[number]second[number]j"`.

I tried to do that like this:

```
char *c_i
int i, j;
if (sscanf(c_i, "first%dsecond%dj", &i, &j) == 2 &&
    c_i[strlen(in) - 2] == 'j') {
    printf("%s", c_i);
}
```

but sscanf ignores everything behind the last number so strings like `"first%dsecond%dthird%dj"` also give the true value and is printed.

Generally `sscanf` cares just about the values of letters before the last specifier and I would like to find something that counts also the letters after, like say a comparer that checks the whole strings and gets any number but number.

Of course I can do that by creating my own `char*` scanner, but I would like to avoid this if there is a simpler way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variation on [@unwind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44000206/2410359)'s good answer.

Use `"%n"` to record the current position in the scan and `"*"` to negate the need for saving to an `int`.

> `n` ... The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to signed integer into which is to be written the number of characters read from the input stream so far by this call to the `fscanf` function. ... C11 §7.21.6.2 12
>
> An optional assignment-suppressing character `*`.  §7.21.6.2 3

```
// return true on match
bool IE_compare(const char *c_i) {
  int n = 0;
  sscanf(c_i, "first%*dsecond%*dj%n", &n);
  return n > 0 && c_i[n] == '\0';
}
```

Note: The format string can be coded as separate sting literals for alternative reading.

```
  sscanf(c_i, "first" "%*d" "second" "%*d" "j" "%n", &n);
```

---

The above will match leading spaces before the number like `"first +123second -456j"` as `"%d"` allows that.  To avoid:

```
  int n1, n2,
  int n = 0;
  sscanf(c_i, "first%n%*dsecond%n%*dj%n", &n1, &n2, &n);
  return n > 0 && !isspace((unsigned char) c_i[n1]) && 
      !isspace((unsigned char) c_i[n2]) && c_i[n] == '\0';
```

The above will match numbers with a  leading *sign* like `"first+123second-456j"` as `"%d"` allows that.  To avoid:

```
  sscanf(c_i, "first%n%*dsecond%n%*dj%n", &n1, &n2, &n);
  return n > 0 && isdigit((unsigned char) c_i[n1]) && 
      isdigit((unsigned char) c_i[n2]) && c_i[n] == '\0';

  // or 
  int n = 0;
  sscanf(c_i, "first%*[0-9]second%*[0-9]j%n", &n);
  return n > 0 && c_i[n] == '\0';
```

---

What remains somewhat unclear is if the occurrence of a number is *required*.  "...and appearance of a number" implies yes.  Should `"firstsecondj"` match?  The above answers assume no.

Comment: That's a really great anwer! You're right, there are to be numbers, "firstsecondj" and "first 2 second    4    j" are both wrong. Thank you! :)

Comment: @IpEsez Tip: As with many coding issues, good code and efficiency follows from precise coding goals.  "number" is too loose.  Leading spaces OK?  No - settled that. A _sign_ OK? What range is valid? Must be an integer? No number OK? For such a small coding task as this, one can code up a number of candidates.  In larger programs, that is not practical.  Sometimes simply listing a number of valid and invalid examples helps a lot.

Comment: I will remember, i'm new to programming and especially posting anything on stackoverflow. Thanks again for advices!

Answer (score 3):

Use `%n` to get the length of the conversion, then check that the string really ends there:

```
void checkString(const char *s)
{
  int i, j, n = 0;

  if (sscanf(s, "first%dsecond%dj%n", &i, &j, &n) == 2 && s[n] == '\0') 
  {
    printf("%s", s);
  }
}
```